# Is there a way to separate a column that has been aggregated into individual columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, delimiter

My SQL query currently is utilizing a LISTAGG to pull all the row data in a table column into one column.
The reason I used a LISTAGG is because there can be an unlimited amount of rows in the column.

I would want to get each of these rows into an individual column to be able to run reports on. This is my current LISTAGG function:

```
 LISTAGG(CE1.DX_NAME, ' ; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CE1.DX_NAME) AS DIAGNOSES
```

Is there a way to separate them from this function into individual columns or any recommendation on if I can use a function without LISTAGG to get my desired results?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is DX_NAME a free text column? Or is it mastered by a reference data table?

Comment: DX_NAME is the name of the Column within the Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... because there can be an unlimited amount of rows in the column

For any query, Oracle must be able to determine the number of columns in the result set, as well as the name and data type of each one, when the query is parsed.  For that reason, there is no reasonable way to submit a query that will return a result set with an arbitrary and data-driven number of columns.  (For an "unreasonable" and really cool way, see: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/).

A lot of this limitation has to do with answering this question: supposing you could submit a query with an arbitrary and data-driven number of columns, how do you expect callers to process such a result set?

A common way to handle requirements like yours is to write a query that returns the data currently in your `LISTAGG` as individual rows and use a reporting too like Qlik or OBIEE or whatever that is capable of crosstabs or pivots in their front end.

Another common way is to put a hard limit on the number of columns.  E.g., if you know your data will never have more than 30 columns, you could then use Gordon's conditional aggregation (see his answer for that).

Answer (score 1):

You can often do what you want using conditional aggregation -- but you need to know the maximum number of columns:

```
select grp,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by col) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Your question lacks specifics, but this shows the general structure for such a query.